# How to forward command line params to the "collateral" make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which looks roughly like this

```
debug: 
  make -C build-debug

release: 
  make -C build-release
```

Now, I run "main" make

```
make -j4 debug
```

How do I forward `-j4` to the collateral make? Note that I don't want to hardcode it, I want to forward whatever was passed to main make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion),:

> If you set [-j] to some numeric value ‘N’ and your operating system
>   supports it (most any UNIX system will; others typically won't), the
>   parent make and all the sub-makes will communicate to ensure that
>   there are only ‘N’ jobs running at the same time between them all...
>   If your operating system doesn't support the above communication, then
>   ‘-j 1’ is always put into MAKEFLAGS instead of the value you
>   specified.

If you *really* want to override this behavior, it's probably not too difficult...

Comment: Don't forget to call the sub-makes with the `${MAKE}` macro. That's how make knows it has to pass on the relevant bits (or the `+` command prefix).

Comment: Bobbogo's comment is key.  You don't have to worry about any sort of argument passing or forwarding to sub-makes or any of that.  All you have to do is use the `$(MAKE)` variable, rather than `make` directly, when you invoke the sub-make.